# WT Forms does not validate_on_submit

Tags: flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-wtforms

I am using Flask, SqlAlchemy, and WT Forms. I have done many forms on this project, but this particular form doesn't submit. I've gone over it several times. I have tried printing `forms.errors` (No errors btw). I have `{{ form.hidden_tag() }}`. I'm pretty sure that it is something simple that I am overlooking.

My html:

```
{% extends "layouts/base.html" %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Add Load</title>
  {% block head %}
  {% endblock %}
<style> 
</style>
</head>
<body>
{% block content %}
<h1>Add Load</h1>
<div class="container">  
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">    
      <form method="POST", action="/loads/add_load">        
        {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
        <div class="form-outline mb-4">                    
          {{ form.broker_id.label }} <br>
          {{ form.broker_id(class_="form-control") }}
        </div>     
        <div class="form-outline mb-4">                    
          {{ form.carrier_id.label }} <br>
          {{ form.carrier_id(class_="form-control", id="select_carrier", onchange="get_drivers()") }}
        </div>    
        <div class="form-outline mb-4">                    
          {{ form.driver_id.label }} <br>
          {{ form.driver_id(class_="form-control", id="select_driver") }}
        </div>    
        <div class="form-outline mb-4">          
          {{ form.load_number.label }} 
          {{ form.load_number(class_="form-control", size=32) }}
        </div>
        <div class="form-outline mb-4">          
          {{ form.rate.label }} 
          {{ form.rate(class_="form-control", size=32) }}
        </div>        
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-4"> 
        <div class="form-outline mb-4">          
          {{ form.weight.label }} 
          {{ form.weight(class_="form-control", size=32) }}
        </div>
        <div class="form-outline mb-4">          
          {{ form.detention_time.label }} 
          {{ form.detention_time(class_="form-control", size=32) }}
        </div>
        <div class="form-outline mb-4">          
          {{ form.detention_fee.label }} 
          {{ form.detention_fee(class_="form-control", size=32) }}
        </div>
        <div class="form-outline mb-4">          
          {{ form.lumper_fee_total.label }} 
          {{ form.lumper_fee_total(class_="form-control", size=32) }}
        </div>
        <div class="form-outline mb-4">          
          {{ form.lumper_fee_paid_by_carrier.label }} 
          {{ form.lumper_fee_paid_by_carrier() }}
        </div>
        
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="form-outline mb-4">          
          {{ form.layover_fee_total.label }} 
          {{ form.layover_fee_total(class_="form-control", size=32) }}
        </div>
        <div class="form-outline mb-4">          
          {{ form.tonu_fee.label }} 
          {{ form.tonu_fee(class_="form-control", size=32) }}
        </div>
        <div class="form-outline mb-4">          
          {{ form.status.label }} 
          {{ form.status(class_="form-control") }}
        </div>
        <div class="form-outline mb-4">          
          {{ form.notes.label }} 
          {{ form.notes(class_="form-control", size=32) }}
        </div>
        <br><br><br><br>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary float-end">Submit</button>
      </form>
      </div> <!--end column-->
  </div> <!--end row-->
</div> <!--end container-->
</body>
{% endblock %}
</html>
```

Form:

```
class AddLoadForm(FlaskForm):
    broker_id = SelectField('Broker', choices=[])
    carrier_id = SelectField('Carrier', choices=[])
    driver_id = SelectField('Driver', choices=[], validators=[InputRequired(), Length(min=1, max=80)])    
    load_number = StringField('Load Number:')
    rate = DecimalField('Rate:')
    weight = IntegerField('Weight')
    detention_time  = IntegerField('Detention Time (minutes)')
    detention_fee = DecimalField('Detention Fee',places=2)
    lumper_fee_total = DecimalField('Lumper Fee Total',places=2)
    lumper_fee_paid_by_carrier = BooleanField('Carrier Pays Lumper Fee')
    layover_fee_total = DecimalField('Layover Fee Total',places=2)
    tonu_fee = DecimalField('TONU Fee',places=2)
    status = SelectField('Status:', choices=load_status_choices)
    notes = TextAreaField('Notes', id="textfield")
```

View Function:

```
@loads_blueprint.route('/add_load', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def add_load():    
    dispatcher_id = current_user.id
    broker_choices = db.session.query(Broker.id, Broker.brokerage_name).filter(current_user.company_id==Broker.dispatch_company_id).all()
    carrier_choices = db.session.query(Carrier.id, Carrier.company_name).filter(current_user.company_id==Carrier.dispatch_company_id).all()
    load = db.session.query(Loads)
    form = AddLoadForm(obj=load)
    form.broker_id.choices = [(b[0], b[1]) for b in broker_choices]
    form.carrier_id.choices = [(c[0], c[1]) for c in carrier_choices]
    print(form.errors,"Before if <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<")
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        print("Form was validated <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<")
        ins = Loads(
            dispatcher_id = dispatcher_id,
            broker_id = int(form.broker_id.data),
            carrier_id = int(form.carrier_id.data),
            driver_id = int(form.driver_id.data),
            load_number = form.load_number.data,
            rate = float(form.rate.data),
            weight = int(form.rate.data),
            detention_time= int(form.detention_time.data),
            detention_fee = float(form.detention_fee.data),
            lumper_fee_total = float(form.lumper_fee_total.data),
            lumper_fee_paid_by_carrier = float(form.lumper_fee_paid_by_carrier.data),
            layover_fee_total = float(form.layover_fee_total.data),
            tonu_fee = float(form.tonu_fee.data),
            status = form.status.data,
            notes = form.notes.data
            )
        db.session.add(ins)
        db.session.commit()        
        #Get ID of added load
        last_load_id = db.session.query(Loads.id).filter(Loads.dispatcher_id==dispatcher_id).order_by(desc(id)).first()
        return redirect(url_for('loads.edit_load',load_id = last_load_id))
    return render_template("/loads/add_load.html", form=form)
```

Here is a version where I replaced `if form.validate_on_submit():` with a try block. It works but I want to be able to use the forms correctly.

```
@loads_blueprint.route('/add_load', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def add_load():    
    dispatcher_id = current_user.id
    broker_choices = db.session.query(Broker.id, Broker.brokerage_name).filter(current_user.company_id==Broker.dispatch_company_id).all()
    carrier_choices = db.session.query(Carrier.id, Carrier.company_name).filter(current_user.company_id==Carrier.dispatch_company_id).all()
    load = db.session.query(Loads)
    form = AddLoadForm()
    form.broker_id.choices = [(b[0], b[1]) for b in broker_choices]
    form.carrier_id.choices = [(c[0], c[1]) for c in carrier_choices]
    
    try: #Couldn't get form to validate on submit
        ins = Loads(
            dispatcher_id = dispatcher_id,
            broker_id = int(form.broker_id.data),
            carrier_id = int(form.carrier_id.data),
            driver_id = int(form.driver_id.data),
            load_number = form.load_number.data,
            rate = float(form.rate.data),
            weight = form.weight.data,
            detention_time= int(form.detention_time.data),
            detention_fee = float(form.detention_fee.data),
            lumper_fee_total = float(form.lumper_fee_total.data),
            lumper_fee_paid_by_carrier = float(form.lumper_fee_paid_by_carrier.data),
            layover_fee_total = float(form.layover_fee_total.data),
            tonu_fee = float(form.tonu_fee.data),
            status = form.status.data,
            notes = form.notes.data
            )
        db.session.add(ins)
        db.session.commit()  
    


        #Get ID of added load
        #last_load_id = db.session.query(Loads.id).filter(Loads.dispatcher_id==dispatcher_id).order_by(desc(id)).first()
        return redirect(url_for('main.dashboard'))
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
    return render_template("/loads/add_load.html", form=form)
```

Comment: Have you tried passing formdata explicitly?

Comment: @TheMonarch I’m not sure what you mean by that. I replaced the if statement with a try block and it works. I would rather do it correctly though.

Comment: It's possible the  validation is failing. Could you remove the obj argument and check form.errors after the if block

Answer (score 0):

Your route is add_load, so you are trying to add. you need to change the following line from:

```
form = AddLoadForm(obj=load)
```

to

```
form = AddLoadForm()
```

if you are using the same route for editing and adding or you want the form to be filled for some reason then use:

```
form = AddLoadForm()
if request.method="GET":
    form = AddLoadForm(obj=load)
```

I hope this will help.

Comment: I am not editing in the same view so I do not need the data to be filled. However, I tried your suggestion and it still doesn't validate on submit. When I replace the if block with a try block everything works, however I would still like to get it working the correct way.

Comment: Can you please share the try block code.

Comment: @Ellie Saad Ok. I edited my post to include the try block. See above.

Comment: I edited my post to include the try block. See above. I also just replaced if form.validate_on_submit(): with form.is_submitted and that also worked. I guess that is a little better, but something is off.

Comment: You can also check the driver_id or the other select fields that you have.  when data comes back from the client it is treated as a string by WTForms unless a callable is passed to the coerce.